# Проблема с Highcharts JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Имеется массив содержащий n-ое кол-во элементов каждый элемент - js код для создания диаграммы на highcharts прим.

```
(
'Animals': {
name: 'Animals',
data: [
['Cows', 2],
['Sheep', 3]
      ]
            } 
)
```

Элементы подобные этому генерируются через цикл и добавляются в массив посредством  `Array.prototype.push()`. Проблема состоит в том, что нужно объединить все элементы не превратив их при этом в строку или число(оставить js кодом), а значит не подходят ни `join`, ни `concat`. Я в ступоре вариантов нет. Относительно того зачем это надо - встроенная в `highcharts` функция добавления в диаграмму подчиненных диаграмм http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown  -не может быть использована несколько раз в итоге получается добавить либо первый элемент массива(в цикле), либо последний элемент(использовать вне цикла). Добавление нескольких подчиненных диаграмм в нашу основную диаграмму получается только посредством написания вышеперечисленного кода ручками.

Comment: Поправте формат кода.

Comment: во что объединять вы хотите?

Comment: В этом то и проблема, что объединять в строку нельзя. Необходимо объединить значения  в объект или переменную.